# Change the content of the animated bar HTML without accessing the source code

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have an HTML page that contains a marquee tag and I want to change the content of this tag without modifying it from source code.

Comment: Well, you can modify it from javascript, you'll still need it to be present on your page. Something like:
`document.getElementById("TheDesiredElement").innerHTML="someContent"; `. Did you mean some other modifications?

Comment: When I get text from an input field
By javascript, therefore, when the page is refreshed, the input field will lose its contents and the tag will lose its contents.
Thank you

Comment: Read [ask] and create a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

You can write a jquery logic like this

`$(marquee-selector).html('');
  $(marquee-selector).html('Your new text');`

Comment: When I get text from an input field
By javascript, therefore, when the page is refreshed, the input field will lose its contents and the tag will lose its contents.
Thank you